# Cannot Manipulate Pelvis Despite other solutions

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, transforms

So I have a model, I want to make a crouch anim, however, I can't edit the pelvis bone despite Having gone to edit mode and unchecked lock, connected as well as the manipulate center point button.

Are there any work arounds to this? Something I'm missing?

Attached is pic to hopefully give a better understanding of what my rig is like, and if I perhaps missed something.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZqkj.jpg

[image]

Comment: Posing a model/rig is done **Armature Pose Mode**, not *Edit Mode*.

Comment: "I can't edit the pelvis bone": It's not clear if you wish to _edit_ that bone (needs edit mode) or _pose_ that bone (needs pose mode).

Comment: Sorry, should clarify, In armature pose mode I cannot manipulate the root bone (pelvis).